# precalculate transform-origin offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, css-transforms

When I change the transform-origin attribute in css3 after a rotation, the element jumps back to the center of the original position.
Is there any way to calculate this distance? I want to make smooth rotations at different origins.

I wrote a formula. It works well, but only if I know the origin from a future rotation.

```
var newx = p2x - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2x - p1x, 2) + Math.pow(p2y - p1y, 2)) * Math.sin( -((degree * (Math.PI/180))) + Math.atan( ((p2x - p1x)/(p2y - p1y)) ));
var newy = p2y - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2x - p1x, 2) + Math.pow(p2y - p1y, 2)) * Math.cos( -((degree * (Math.PI/180))) + Math.atan( ((p2x - p1x)/(p2y - p1y)) ));
```

p1x and p1y are the values from the future, p2x and p2y are the origin from the current rotation.

Comment: You are trying to rotate an object around the origin which is not the center. Is it so?
Which values are p1x and p1y? Are they center?
Can you please make it more clear?

Comment: p1x and p1y are the x and y coordinates of a origin point. They are not the center. p1 is the origin of the next rotation in the future. p2x and p2y are also coordinates but from the current rotation. The problem is, I don't know what happen in the future and can't predict p1x and p1y

Comment: In this fiddle you can see the problem if I use current and last origin points, or if I didn't try to calculate the offset. http://jsfiddle.net/jul35/Cj9TZ/6/

Comment: As a side-note: In your fiddle `var currentorigin = $(this).css("-webkit-transform-origin").split(" ");` gave me issues in FF. Had to change it to `-moz-...` instead. Just in case someone else is trying to figure out why the fiddle is not working in FF.

Comment: Pff, this one is easy, all you need is a time machine :D